# Finding the maximum value of a function found from a differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, functions, graphing-functions

I solved a differential equation and got the function $Q=\frac{t}{2}e^{-\frac{t}{20}}$. I am being asked to then find the point in which the value is at its maximum. One solution approach I can think of is taking the derivative of this function and finding where it is equal to zero, and then plugging those values to see which is the largest.

I am curious if there is a better approach to this problem, while the derivative is rather trivial to find, it seems like a better approach might exist.

Comment: Your approach is quite ok! Can you show us the differential equation?

Comment: It's actually a modeling problem, so I wanted to make give the solutions rather than the problem itself. But you can view the problem here: https://i.imgur.com/zkCSWaf.png

Comment: There’s no better approach!

Comment: Thank you! @Fakemistake